# Printing list indexes from nested dictionaries containing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to print from a dictionary that is made up of a nested dictionary and a list.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble printing items from the list with `length > 1`.  Here is my code:

```
animals = {
    'cats': {
                'name': 'moose', 
                'color': 'black & white', 
                'alias':'Moosalini'
            },
    'dogs': {
                'name': ['scout', 'sulley'],
                'color': 'white & orange',
                'alias': ['skump', 'skulley']
            }
    }

for animal_type, animal_info in animals.items():
    print('Animal type: ', animal_type)
    for key in animal_info:
        print(key + ': ' + animal_info[key])
```

The output is exactly what I want until it gets to the list associated with `'name'` under the key `'dogs'`.  My code will not concatenate the list because it is not a string.  I thought one could concatenate lists just like strings?

```
Animal type:  cats
name: moose
color: black & white
alias: Moosalini
Animal type:  dogs
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Jaron/Documents/nested dictionary.py", line 14, in <module>
    print ( key + ': ' + animal_info[key])
    TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I tried placing the str() function in front of the animal_info[key], which allows the concatenation but includes the list bracketing like this.

```
Animal type:  dogs
name: ['scout', 'sulley']
color: white & orange
alias: ['skump', 'skulley']
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
Animal type: cats
name: moose
color: black & white
alias: Moosalini
Animal type: dogs
name: scout, sulley
color: black & white
alias: skump, skulley
```

How does one specify the item index in a list within a dictionary that is within a nested dictionary so the string concatenation will work? Also, is there a way to make it so that the concatenation of lists will work with the program without keeping the list brackets, []?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Note you can more easily just loop over `for key, value in animals.items():` Anyway, one *can* concatenate `list` objects, *to other list objects*, however, you are trying to concatenate a `list` and a `str` object, which will fail. You need to check and see if you are working with a list or a str. Ideally, you would fix whatever is giving you this messy output into something mroe regular (they should all be lists, for example)

Answer (score 2):

You have to join lists to convert them to strings before being concatenated to strings. This is possible using `join()`:

```
animals ={'cats':{'name': 'moose', 'color':'black & white', 'alias':'Moosalini'},
           'dogs':{'name':['scout', 'sulley'], 'color': 'white & orange',
           'alias': ['skump', 'skulley']}}

for animal_type, animal_info in animals.items():
    print(f'Animal type: {animal_type}')
    for key, value in animal_info.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            print(f"{key}: {', '.join(value)}")
        else:
            print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join method (string):

```
if isinstance(animal_info[key], list):
    print(key + ':' + ','.join(animal_info[key]);
```